# Bring uniq values with rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I want to bring the last messages by the `receiver_id`.
If a do

```
::Message.where(recipient_id:recipient_id).ascending
```

I get all the messages send to `recipient_id` but I want to bring one for each sender. How can I limit this?

I have tried

```
::Message.where(recipient_id:recipient_id).ascending.uniq
```

with no success

Comment: "one for each sender" ? how do you check this?

Comment: Better if you add how the models are related. There should be a sender foreign key over there.

Comment: there is a sender foreign key, but I want  to use something like a `distinct` by sender, but I don't know how to do that in rails, or if it is possible

Comment: `Message.where(recipient_id:recipient_id).group(:sender_id)`. I'm just guessing...

Comment: Like @SebastianPalma said, use group.